# Data not displaying from service with dynamic parameter

Tags: angularjs

not sure what I have wrong here but the data doesn't display with this code and the only error I get is an XML Reading error XML in booksincategory.html , any ideas? Thanks

**booksincategory.html **

```
<div class="category col" ng-repeat="book in detail">
      <h3 class="title">{{book.title}}</h3>
  </div>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('BookCategoryController', ['$scope', 'bookcategories', '$routeParams',  function($scope, bookcategories, $routeParams) {
    bookcategories.getAllBooks($scope.id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.detail = response.data.books[$routeParams.categoryId];
  });
}]);
```

**service**

```
app.service('bookcategories', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getAllBooks: function(id) {
      return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/'+ id + '/books.json')
     }
  }
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('ReaderApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/categories/:categoryId', {
    controller: 'BookCategoryController',
    templateUrl: 'views/booksincategory.html'
})
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/books'
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- Modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/BookCategoryController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/services/bookcategories.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you add the error log output? And the response data?

Comment: to what state does '/books' point? Could you paste the definition too?